# React Native Android / iOS call function on app start

Tags: android, react-native, event-handling

I am new to React Native.

I am trying to call a react native method from native code without having any UI components from RN.

The idea is to add a DeviceEmitter listener at application start and later on post events from Native code.

The question is where should I put JS code to add DeviceEmitter listener at app start?

Answer (score 0):

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.44/appregistry#registerheadlesstask

AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask is probably where you should start.